# Accidently created stackdrive workspace account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

I am complete beginner, was trying my hand on google cloud free tier.

Accidentally created stackdriver workspace with default google cloud project.

Will there be charges for it? Does agent by default send logging data to stackdriver?

If yes then how can we disable or delete it.
Please if anyone can let me know.

Thanks
Sourabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to worry about. At first, have a look at the [Pricing for Operations](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#per-project) documentation where you can find [Chargeable services](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#chargeable-products):

> This table provides a summary of the pricing details (also read the
>   Pricing notes on this page):

[image: pricing]

As you can see, **you have a lot of `Free allotment per month` for Chargeable services**. Also, check documentation [Google Cloud Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) where you can find more details about [12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) and [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) program.

In addition, have a look at the [Creating and managing workspaces](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/manage) and [Deleting a Workspace](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/manage#delete-account).